# Epimorphism in the functor category $[\mathbf{C}^{op}, \mathbf{Set}]$

Tags: category-theory

Let $\mathbf{C}$ be a small category and $\alpha: F \Rightarrow G$ be a morphism in the functor category $Func(\mathbf{C}^{op}, \mathbf{Set})$. How do I prove that $\alpha$ is an epimorphism if and only if for all $A \in \mathbf{C}$ we have that $\alpha_A : FA \rightarrow GA$ is surjetive? Any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ be categories, $\mathcal{F},\mathcal{G}\colon\mathcal{A}\to\mathcal{B}$ be functors, $\alpha\colon\mathcal{F}\to\mathcal{G}$ be a natural transformation.

If $\alpha(a)$ is an epimorphism for every $a\in\text{Obj}(A)$, then $\alpha$ is an epimorphism in $\text{Func}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$. It is an easy exercise.

If $\alpha$ is an epimorphism in $\text{Func}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ and $\mathcal{B}$ is finitely cocomplete, then $\alpha(a)$ is an epimorphism in $\mathcal{B}$ for every $a\in\text{Obj}(\mathcal{A})$. For every object $a\in\text{Obj}(\mathcal{A})$ denote by $\Delta_a\colon\mathbf{1}\to\mathcal{A}$ such functor, that $\Delta_a(0)=a$. Note, that if $\mathcal{B}$ is finitely cocomplete, then the inverse image functor $\mathcal{B}^{\Delta_a}\colon\mathcal{B}^{\mathcal{A}}\to\mathcal{B}^{\mathbf{1}}$ is right exact. Therefore, the evaluation functor $\text{ev}_a\colon\mathcal{B}^{\mathcal{A}}\to\mathcal{B}$, such that $\text{ev}_a(\mathcal{T})=\mathcal{T}(a)$ for every $\mathcal{T}\in\text{Func}(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$, which is isomorphic to $\mathcal{B}^{\Delta_a}$, preserves epimorphisms.

Then it is sufficient to note that $\mathbf{Set}$ is finitely cocomplete.

Of course, the only difficult part of the proof is the statement that the inverse image functor preserves pointwise colimits. You can read about the theory of pointwise limits/colimits in the Mac Lane's CFWM and in the Borceux's handbook.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{B}^{\Delta_0}$? Does $\mathcal{A}$ need to have zero object?

Comment: @user435800 Inverse image functor. You can find its definition in my old answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1663325/action-of-functors-between-functor-categories/1663722#1663722

Comment: @user435800 $\mathcal{A}$ may be arbitraty.

Comment: @user435800 By $\mathbf{1}$ I denote the trivial category with one object and one morphism ($\text{Obj}(\mathbf{1})=\{0\}$).

Comment: @user435800 Ah, sorry, it was a typo, thanks. Not $\Delta_0$, but $\Delta_a$.

Comment: Thanks for  the answer, one last question: why $ev_a$ and $\mathcal{B}^{\Delta_a}$ are isomorphic?

Comment: @user435800 It is a consequence of the isomorphism $\mathcal{B}\cong \mathcal{B}^{\mathbf{1}}$. Functors from the trivial category to $\mathcal{B}$ "are" objects of $\mathcal{B}$. And it should be noted, that they are not isomorphic in a functor category (they have different codomains), but in the arrow category of $\mathbf{Cat}$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a direct calculational argument..
\begin{align*}
\quad& \text{ each } α_A : F\,A → G\;A \text{ is epic } \\
 ≡   & \color{green}{\{\text{ Definition of epic }\}} \\
     & \quad ∀ A • ∀ g,h •  \quad h ∘ α_A = g ∘ α_A ⇒ h = g  \\
≡    & \color{green}{\{\text{ ⇒ take h,g to be transformation; ⇐ take ε,η to be constantly h,g }\}} \\
     &\quad ∀ A • ∀ η,ε • \quad η_A ∘ α_A = ε_A ∘ α_A ⇒ η_A = ε_A \\
≡   &\color{green}{\{\text{ Composition of natural transformations }\}} \\
    &\quad ∀ A • ∀ η,ε • \quad (η ∘ α)_A = (ε ∘ α)_A ⇒ η_A = ε_A \\
≡   & \color{green}{\{\text{ Quantifier Nesting }\}} & \\
    & \quad ∀ η,ε • ∀ A • \quad (η ∘ α)_A = (ε ∘ α)_A ⇒ η_A = ε_A &\\
\Rightarrow & \color{green}{\{\text{ Quantifier distributivity }\}} \\
   & \quad ∀ η,ε • \left(∀ A •\; (η ∘ α)_A = (ε ∘ α)_A \right) ⇒ \left(∀ A •\; η_A = ε_A\right) \\
≡ & \color{green}{\{\text{ Extensionality }\}} \\
  & \quad ∀ η,ε •\quad η ∘ α = ε ∘ α ⇒ η = ε \\
≡ & \color{green}{\{\text{ Definition of epic }\}} \\
  & \quad α \text{ is epic }
\end{align*}

Note that the since in Set, epic is precisely surjective, the desired result follows --more or less.

Comment: In the second equivalence, what exactly do you mean by “take $ε$, $η$ to be constantly $h$, $g$”? It seems to me that this step assumes that every two maps $g, h \colon GA \to X$ can be extended to natural transformation $η, ε \colon G \Rightarrow H$ for a suitable functor $H$ (with $H(A) = X$). But I don’t see why this should be true.